# Display the most recent data for multilevel dropdown with custom query?

Tags: mysql, yii

I have mutasi_alat table, where a tool(alat) can transferred to different locations according to the date of enactment. Here I use the most recent id to determine the location of new field this id_alat.

```
id | id_alat | tgl_berlaku | id_cabang
2  | 4       | 2013-10-21  | 4
3  | 4       | 2013-10-22  | 5
4  | 5       | 2013-10-21  | 6
5  | 4       | 2013-10-23  | 2
6  | 8       | 2013-10-21  | 4
7  | 4       | 2013-10-24  | 3
8  | 5       | 2013-10-24  | 4
9  | 6       | 2013-10-25  | 6
```

and the table alat is :

```
id  | kode     | nama  
4   | 01020001 | A1
5   | 01020002 | A2
6   | 01020003 | A3
8   | 01020004 | A4
```

result : when in dropdown post data bring a value id_cabang, this value for condition select id_alat in table mutasi_alat.
I was confused for this problem. help me..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved  yes..
:)

```
SELECT kode, nama FROM alat WHERE id IN ( SELECT id_alat FROM mutasi_alat WHERE id IN 
( SELECT id FROM mutasi_alat WHERE id IN ( SELECT MAX( id ) AS id FROM mutasi_alat GROUP BY id_alat)) 
AND id_cabang =4 )
```

Comment: how make dependent dropdown with custom query like this in Yii?? @tinyByte